# How can i assign tasks to several machines in my ethernet?

Tags: multithreading, cluster-computing

I have a big tasks which can be seperated into several small tasks.

For Example,

The Tasks load data from input file, based on those data, calculate some results, then dump into output file.

each task handle different file, wont have any conflicits.

Assume I have 100 small tasks, each task will cost 1s, if i run them in one machine by single thread, it will cost me 100s.

I tried multi-threading, i have 20 cores, even i used thread_pool, it only can reduce time to 50s( and 3 cores-20 cores make no difference), I spend a lot of time on multi-threading, but can make it better. I think it may be caused by false-sharing or some other complex problems, i cant understand yet.

So, I am thinking if there is some easy way i can use to assign these problems into different machines in my ethernet.

In my imagination, the good ways is:

every machine installed same software, and in my control machine, i just run a command to assign tasks to those machine. they compute, when finished, the control machine collect result back, so, it speed up, and got same result  with single machine.

if i have 10 machines, i will expect the time can be reduced to 10s(10% of 100s).

Is there any easy ways can be used for a rockie?

Comment: Read about cluster managers / job schedulers like SLURM.  (Don't reinvent the wheel.  People have been doing this stuff for 30+ years.)

Comment: Mind you, most job schedulers are unsuitable for tasks that only take 1 second to complete.  They are generally used when job times are measured in hours or days.  For small tasks you probably need a simpler model based on message queues; e.g. https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/distributed-task-scheduler-redis-329475df9dcf

Comment: @StephenC thanks, so, the best practice may be use message queue to collect data from different servers? but how to assign tasks down, is there any simple tutorials?

Comment: You don't assign tasks.  You just put them in the queue.  The worker processes on the servers pick them off the queue and process them one at a time.  (Requesting links is off-topic.  Google is your friend.  Or just read the link I gave you above.)